# Getting method arguments into a list of key and value pairs

Tags: python

I'm looking to get each of my method parameters into a dictionary or tuple pairs in a list as later the arguments get put through `urllib.urlencode` and formed into a POST statement.

I got as far as this from other SO questions

```
def func(a,b,c,d,e=None,f=None):
  values= locals()
  data= dict((k,v) for k,v in values.iteritems() if v is not None)
```

This second line just strips out the optional arguments not used. The problem with this is because I'm using this as POST data later I need the order of the arguments to be maintained.

So is there a similar way of doing the above but I guess avoiding the use of dictionaries because they are orderless?

EDIT: I might have just overlooked something completely.. I can send values through POST in any order right?

Comment: How can I change what type `locals()` uses, into a list or ordered dict? I was aware of ordered dictionaries but isn't the order already lost in the locals dict?

Comment: Ah yes, brainfart on my side. Please excuse the confusion.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the `inspect` module?

Comment: Why don't you just use *args? Because of keyword arguments? Can't you explicitly state them like on your question?

Comment: i thought about *args and **kwargs but because it will be a public api for web service I wanted to lock down which arguments are required and which are optional with the argument names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST data is treated as unordered 99.99999% of the time (or maybe even more).  Don't worry about the ordering.